# Is a Gazan woman running for Office in Belgium?

Tags: politics, media

I am currently researching some information about Gazans who manage to emigrate in order to improve [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/4882/can-one-leave-the-gaza-strip-permanently/41587?noredirect=1#comment162013_41587). During this process I have found what it seems to be [an interesting article](https://unitedwithisrael.org/gazan-woman-runs-for-office-in-belgium-plans-to-defend-palestinian-refugees/) about Gazan community in Belgium and more precise about a Gazan woman running for Office there:

> Leila Wafi, who hails from Khan Yunis in the Gaza Strip, is running
>   for office in the Belgian Parliament.
>
> Wafi currently leads the Palestinian Women Union in Belgium. She has
>   stated that if elected, she will promote the “rights of Palestinian
>   refugees” in Belgium and will defend them throughout Europe.

I am trying to double check this information, but I am finding very limited information and only for Israeli sites (e.g. [Jewish Press](https://www.jewishpress.com/news/global/europe/gazan-woman-running-for-office-in-belgian-parliament/2019/04/15/)).

**Question:** Is a Gazan woman running for Office in Belgium?

As a side note, but related, any information related to Gazan community size is also appreciated.

Comment: How is this claim "notable"?  At least 11 members of the US Congress were not born as US citizens, and no doubt hundreds of lower offices.  And 27 British MPs were born outside the UK.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - not sure about it being "notable", but all English sources arguing about it seem to be Israeli, so I was a bit skeptic about this information. `Schmuddi` proved that I should have searched for information in French on German.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Leila Wafi is [on the Be.One electorial list](https://wahlen2019.belgium.be/en/preference-votes?el=BR&id=BRK21009&party=384) for the district of Ixelles in Brussels. [Be.One](https://www.beone.be/index.php/a-propos-de-nous) describes itself as

> Le parti pour le renouveau politique et l’égalité radicale 
>   ("the party for political renewal and radical equality", my translation)

According to [an article](https://www.bruzz.be/brussel-kiest-2019/brussel-kiest-brussels-parlement/nieuwe-namen-voor-kieslijsten-van-beone-2019-03) from Belgium magazine Bruzz, Wafi arrived in Belgium in 2004 as a student of Social and Political Science, and is now a resident of Belgium where she owns a family business. The article also confirms that she is the founder of the Palestinan Women Union in Belgium, which assists newly-arrived Palestinan women in their social-professional integration courses.